# Nested for loop to vectorized function and saving value in dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, apply, lookup

I have a very large output and need to put this in a table. There should be 3380 rows and 250 columns and the table should look like this

[image: this]. (=input_template_df_0)

Then I have another table with the output that has the column names and row names each in a column and looks like this

[image: this]. (=input_lofreq_4)

I know how to do this with a nested for loop, but as you can imagine this takes a long (!) time. I'm not (yet) very good with apply and vectorized functions, so I'm hoping that someone in this community can help me with transforming my function to a faster one?

PS: there is also an if function, because not all combinations will be found in input_lofreq_4

```
for(i in 1:length(rownames(input_template_df_0))){
  for(j in 1:length(colnames(input_template_df_0))){
   if(!is_empty(as.numeric(as.character(input_lofreq_4[input_lofreq_4$selectrow==rownames(input_template_df_0)[i] & input_lofreq_4$selectcolumn==colnames(input_template_df_0)[j],"VF"])))) {
  input_template_df_0[i,j] <- as.numeric(as.character(input_lofreq_4[input_lofreq_4$selectrow==rownames(input_template_df)[i] & input_lofreq_4$selectcolumn==colnames(input_template_df_0)[j],"VF"]))
  }
  }
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I made simplified dataframes

```
selectrow <- c("5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059072","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059238","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059260","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059092","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059204","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059123","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059282","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059072","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059238","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059260","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059092","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059204","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059123","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059282","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059072","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059238","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059260","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059092","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059204","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059123","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059282")

selectcolumn <- c("C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059286","C913T_ERR5059286","C913T_ERR5059286","C913T_ERR5059286","C913T_ERR5059286","C913T_ERR5059286","C913T_ERR5059286")

VF <- c("0.51","0.48","0.52","0.49","0.5","0.5","0.48","0.52","0.51","0.52","0.5","0.5","0.48","0.5","0.5","0.48","0.49","0.51","0.5","0.48","0.52")
input_lofreq_4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(selectrow, selectcolumn, VF))

input_template_df_0 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 7))
colnames(input_template_df_0) <- c("C913T_ERR5059114","C913T_ERR5059253","C913T_ERR5059286")
rownames(input_template_df_0) <- c("5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059072","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059238","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059260","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059092","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059204","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059123","5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059282")

input_template_df_0
input_lofreq_4
```

Comment: I added a simplified dataframe of how the data looks like. This is really a very small part of it of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `lapply` :

```
rn <- rownames(input_template_df_0)

input_template_df_0[] <- lapply(names(input_template_df_0), function(x) {
  with(input_lofreq_4, VF[rn == selectrow & selectcolumn == x])  
})

input_template_df_0
#                            C913T_ERR5059114 C913T_ERR5059253 C913T_ERR5059286
#5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059072             0.51             0.52              0.5
#5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059238             0.48             0.51             0.48
#5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059260             0.52             0.52             0.49
#5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059092             0.49              0.5             0.51
#5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059204              0.5              0.5              0.5
#5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059123              0.5             0.48             0.48
#5000X-WT50-MUT50_ERR5059282             0.48              0.5             0.52
```

---

If there are certain values which are in the dataframe you can use :

```
tmp <- paste(input_lofreq_4$selectrow, input_lofreq_4$selectcolumn, sep = '-')
input_template_df_0[] <- input_lofreq_4$VF[match(outer(rownames(input_template_df_0), 
                         colnames(input_template_df_0), paste, sep = '-'), tmp)]
```

Comment: Thank you for you help!! It works very well if all data in "input_lofreq_4" is present. Can an "if" function be introduced in an lapply? For example if there is an extra row or extra column where only a few can be found in the "input_lofreq_4" that it fills an "NA"?

Comment: Can you take a look at the my updated answer @LauraVP ? It does not require an explicit `if` condition to check, since we are using `match` here it will automatically return `NA` for values that are not present.